# HTTP with encrypted message vs HTTPS

Tags: tls, web-application, http, api

A bit of background:

I am a web developer and sometimes i integrate some form of external API in my web applications.

It's the second time already that i find something strange: some APIs instead of accepting messages through HTTPS, require that i send the message over HTTP using some encryption algorithm to encrypt it.

This algorithm is custom made by the API provider and always involves multiple "rounds" of encryption, i think to make the message as secure as possible.

I can't really think of a good reason to why this solution is better, so my question is:

Is there any advantage in using HTTP with an encrypted message instead of HTTPS? Is it common to do this?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately i cannot share much about the API but here are some more details:

Basically i need to implement a code snippet given by the API provider that is used to encrypt the HTTP payload, it goes something like:

```
public string Encrypt(string message)
{
    //do stuff with md5 and triple DES
    return encryptedmessage;
}
```

But that's outside the scope of the question, i **know** for sure that a message needs to be encrypted using *that* function and sent over HTTP.

Comment: "custom algorithm" is a huge red flag in security.

Comment: TLS is a very mature protocol.  It has had years to evolve, it is simple to deploy, and it handles all three requirements necessary for any secure protocol (i.e. secrecy, integrity, and authenticity) as well as any other secure protocol.  Newer versions (e.g. TLS 1.3) offer perfect forward secrecy as well.  It's difficult to imagine use case where it would be preferable to deploy a home-grown protocol instead of TLS for end-to-end client-server encryption.

Comment: @mti2935 The only "use case" I can genuinely think of is to make it easier to crack the encryption algorithm.

Comment: @MechMK1,  good point.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: @MechMK1 maybe "custom algorithm" is not the right word. Basically it encrypts a string in UTF8, then the encrypted string gets re-encrypted in MD5 and the last step is a T-DES encryption, or something along those lines

Comment: Apart from that payload encryption instead or in addition to transport level encryption (HTTPS) makes sense if the HTTP endpoint is not the one which should finally process the data and is not trusted enough to have access to the decrypted data. Just imagine when a CDN like Cloudflare is used for DoS protection. This can see all traffic since it works as a HTTPS endpoint.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich updated the question. But my doubt still remains

Comment: Anyone using 3DES for security does not know anything about security...

Comment: In addition to what the other commenters have mentioned, the client and the server would need to agree on a shared secret key for the 3DES encryption.  How is this key derived (or shared)?  Also, how does the client know that it is in fact communicating with the server, and not a man-in-the-middle attacker?  These thorny details have all been worked out in TLS.

Comment: Ok, so basically the answer to my question is a solid "no". Understood!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any advantage in using HTTP with an encrypted message instead of HTTPS?

No, and I can list a handful of disadvantages:

- It's not properly tested and vetted
- Homegrown code usually lacks quality
- It creates a huge point of failure because the developer is not a cryptographer
- It's not easily updated with better algorithms
- It's not secure
- It performs badly
- It complicates the code without adding any benefits

> Is it common to do this?

Unfortunately yes, it's common. It's "[Schneier's Law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html)" working:

> Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can’t break.

Developers aren't cryptographers, so they devise ways to encrypt data that do not work well, and it's way worse than anything already done. They do this because they don't know enough of crypto to know their code isn't secure at all, and because they don't know enough of crypto to know the alternatives. Throwing XOR and MD5 and DES on the blender can return opaque looking strings, but returning opaque AND secure strings is a very different thing.

Should it be done like this? Absolutely not.

If the backend for some strange, bizarre reason cannot use HTTPS, at least use proper encryption. There are good libraries out there that can properly handle encryption ([NaCl](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/) for example), so use one of them.

And if you can, bully the dev on the other side to employ good crypto. If you cannot bully him, find someone that can.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Unfortunately i cannot really bully anyone into using TLS and it's not really in my paygrade to do it. All i can say is that at least, from my end, anything encryption-wise it's done "the right way". Also, one of those two companies is one of the biggest in the sector i'm working in, at least in my country

Comment: Send an anonymous email to Full Disclosure mailing list, let the world shame them into behaving. It's 21th century already, crypto from the 60's aren't allowed anymore...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the *custom algorithm* is. If it is a home made one, it is an evidence of poor security practices. The rule for crypto is **don't roll your own**, except for experts and experts know that a new *thing* can only be used in production after extensive reviews.

That being said, there can be use cases for development teams. It is common for medium to large organizations to setup Deep Packet Inspection at the firewall level for all incoming connections except for the production DMZ. An immediate side effect is that external HTTPS connections from the outside to a dev machine are forbidden while HTTP ones are allowed. If a dev has to setup a temporary incoming server, it may be simpler and quicker to use a well know crypting tool over raw HTTP than installing it in HTTPS in the production zone. But as it defeats the DPA goal, it should only be used for temporary apps. But I would bet a coin that it is commonly used in research centers as a security/useability balance...

---

There is another difference.

When you use HTTPS, you blindly trust a number of infrastucture components: the server firewall, and possibly the client one. At the server side, it is common for the HTTPS protocol to be unwrapped on a proxy, and everything to be in clear text in the computer center. In corporate organization, it is common to have Deep Packet Inspection implemented as a Man In The Middle Attack on the corporate proxy: a special CA certificate valid for any domain is installed on the client machines and the HTTPS packets are decrypted on the firewall and encrypted again *using that special certificate*. Exchanging encrypted data over HTTP is a guarantee of end to end encryption whatever the infrastructure.

Comment: Updated the question, maybe it's a bit more clear. This method will be used in a production environment too